# Azure B2C SSO with OWIN

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, owin, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

we are trying to achieve the following scenario involving two applications:

1. Both Web Applications APP1 and APP2 use Azure B2C Authentication
2. User goes to APP1. Authentication Required, APP1 redirects to APP2
3. APP2 authenticates against Azure B2C and then allows the user to select a setting which is stored in a cookie. Once done user is redirected back to APP1
4. APP1 should now also be authenticated as it uses Azure B2C and SSO is configured in the policies.
   My issue is in step 4, APP1 won't recognize that the user already signed in against AB2C via APP2.

   ```
           var cookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
       {
           CookieDomain = ".app.localhost",
           CookieName = "IAMAuthentication",
           ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
           SlidingExpiration = true,
           CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
           LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
           LogoutPath = new PathString("/logout"),
           Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
           {
               OnApplyRedirect = ApplyCookieRedirect
           }
       };

       var openIdAuthOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
       {
           RedirectUri = RedirectUri,
           ClientId = ClientId,
           Authority = string.Format(AadInstance, ApiTenant, SignInPolicy),
           TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { NameClaimType = "name", SaveSigninToken = true },
           PostLogoutRedirectUri = RedirectUri
       };

       app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
       app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthenticationOptions);

       app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openIdAuthOptions);

       app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
   ```

Comment: Can you host App1 and App2 as subdomains. It is possible that the Auth cookie from the App2 are not available on App1. You may also need a shared Machine key for App1 and App2 so they can share the auth cookie.

Comment: Hello this is an interesting problem because this happens in some apps but not all. And the OWIN startup class is in a shared library. The problem is that in some cases, APP2 wont have its context.Current.User set by the middleware for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a missing configuration in the tenant.